# Is it possible to call C# dlls from Visual Basic code contained in a Word 2007 file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

I have some Visual Basic methods that are acting as the click handlers for a custom Word Ribbon.  Unfortunately, I already have the implementation of what the handlers have to do written in C# which is loaded into the Word document as an XML Expansion Pack.

I don't see any way to add a reference to the C# .dlls to Word's Visual Basic Editor.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# component would have to expose a COM interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx.